# Shiny no longer accepts reactive function for xreg value

Tags: r, shiny, arima, forecast

I have been working on a shiny app which uses `auto.arima()` from the package, along with an `xreg` parameter.  For some reason, the `xreg` function (which takes a data frame or matrix) has stopped accepting the output of a reactive function - which is a subsetted dataframe. The work-around sucks, and so I'm hoping someone knows a good way to fix this.

Shiny produces this ERROR:

> xreg should be a numeric matrix or vector

I've tried:

- re-installing: forecast, shiny, dplyr, and completing wiping our R and Rstudio, and re-installing from scratch.
- I've tried rolling back the forecast package to the build from 6 months ago (when this was working)
- I've tried rolling back R to the build from 6 months ago (when this was working)
- I've tried using other forecast packages; bsts for example seems to work just fine

This is some minimally viable shiny code. Create a .csv with 3 columns of data, be sure to name the columns, like `y`, `x1` and `x2`.

```
 library(shiny)
 library(forecast)
 library(dplyr)


 ui <- fluidPage(

 # Application title
 titlePanel("arima test"),

 # Sidebar with a slider input for number of bins 
 sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
     
    # Input: Select a file ----
    fileInput("uploaded_file", "Choose CSV File",
              multiple = TRUE,
              accept = c("text/csv",
                         "text/comma-separated-values,text/plain",
                         ".csv")),
    
    uiOutput("dv_dropdown"),
    uiOutput("iv_checkbox")
    
  ),
  
  # Show a plot of the generated distribution
  mainPanel(
    verbatimTextOutput("model"),
    tableOutput('data')
  )
  )
  )


 server <- function(input, output) {

 # Read .csv file ----
   df <- reactive({
   req(input$uploaded_file)
   read.csv(input$uploaded_file$datapath,
         header = TRUE)

   })

 # Dynamically generate a list of the dependent variables for the user to choose from the uploaded .csv ----
   output$dv_dropdown <- renderUI({

   selectInput(inputId = "select_dependents", 
            label = "dependent time series:", 
            choices = names(df()[,c(-1)])
            )
   })

 # Dynamically generate a list of the independent variables for the user to choose ----
   output$iv_checkbox <- renderUI({

   checkboxGroupInput(inputId = "select_ivs", 
                   label = "Select Independent variables:", 
                   choices = setdiff(names(df()[,c(-1)]), input$select_dependents),
                   selected = setdiff(names(df()), input$select_dependents))
    })


 ####### CREATE REACTIVE DATA OBJECTS BASED ON FILTERS #################

 # this creates a dataframe of the dependent time series
 df_sel <- reactive({
   req(input$select_dependents)
   df_sel <- df() %>% select(input$select_dependents)


 })

 # this creates a dataframe of the dependent time series
 df_indep <- reactive({
   req(input$select_ivs)
   df_indep <- df() %>% select(input$select_ivs) 

 })


 #proof that the independent variables are in fact in a matrix/dataframe
   output$data <- renderTable({
   df_indep()
  }) 


#This is the TEST ARIMA Model 

 modela <- reactive({
 
 modela <- auto.arima(df_sel(), xreg = df_indep()) #model with regressors
 #modela <- auto.arima(df_sel()) #model without regressors to demonstrate that it actually works without the xreg argument
 })

 #this is the solution to the xreg problem above, but there's no reason I can think of that xreg shouldn't be able to take a reactive data object like it was doing before... 
 #x = as.matrix(as.data.frame(lapply(df_indep(), as.numeric))) 
 # then set: xreg = x 
 

 output$model <- renderPrint({ 
 summary(modela())
 })




 }

 # Run the application 
 shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Are you certain it's not `NULL`? I suggest you add `browser()` as the first line of `modela <- reactive({ ... })`, and see what `df_indep()` looks like. If it is `NULL` and that's causing the error, consider adding `req(df_indep())` as the first line, which will prevent that reactive block from trying to fire until `df_indep()` is "truthy" (see [`?req`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/shiny/versions/1.3.0/topics/req) for what that means).

Comment: I attempted req(df_indep()) just now; same effect.  I'm trying to figure out to read the output of the browser()

Comment: also, the table output here: 

#proof that the independent variables are in fact in a matrix/dataframe
   output$data <- renderTable({
   df_indep()
  })

shows that the object df_indep() is not null.

Comment: When you placed `browser()` at the beginning of that reactive block, confirmed `df_indep()` was non-`NULL` and structured like you expect, and then ran `auto.arima(df_sel(), xreg = df_indep())` ***manually***, did it work? If not, then this question might have nothing to do with `shiny`, and more with your data and/or how the process deals with various corner-cases.

Comment: (Another question: at that point, is `df_sel()` also not `NULL`?)

Comment: I have the browser() output..  there does not appear to be an instance of null that I can see.   Actually,  Browser just returns "Error:"    I have a prompt like this:  Browse[1]>   and a wrote: auto.arima(df_sel(), xreg = df_indep())  at the prompt.   it returned "Error:"

Comment: df_sel() is not null, because the the renderTable function returns a table showing the columns of data that I selected.   it seems to be a problem with how the xreg is interpreting the reactive function, as far as I can tell.

Comment: Oh, right. I believe the reactive block might have you in a `sink`. Inside `browser()`, type `sink(NULL)` (perhaps multiple times), and then `arima...`, and you should now see the error. Another thought, though confidence is low: try assigning locally first, as `a <- df_sel(); b <- df_indep(); auto.arima(a, xreg=b)`.

Comment: Oh wait ... `xreg=` needs a vector or matrix, but you are giving it a `tibble`. What happens if you force it to be a vector or matrix?

Comment: working on this, but it might be helpful to know that when I removed the auto.arima argument, and just told the reactive function to print df_indep(), it did exactly that.

Comment: whoa... what's a tibble?
well, I already tried do this (which works), but as a solution, its terrible. 
#x = as.matrix(as.data.frame(lapply(df_indep(), as.numeric)))

Comment: You are using `dplyr`. A `tibble` is an "enhanced `data.frame`". More the point: when you verify that `df_indep()` is not `NULL`, exactly what type of object is it? Does `class(df_indep())` include `"tbl_df"`?

Comment: `dplyr::select` returns a `tibble`. `dplyr::pull` returns a vector. If you are always pulling just one column, I suggest you use the latter. If you are potentially pulling multiple columns, then you should probably add `%>% as.matrix()` to the inner-end of your `df_indep <- reactive(...)` block.

Comment: solved!  brilliant.

df_indep <- df() %>% select(input$select_ivs) %>% as.matrix()

thank you so much!   So I can implicate perhaps an update to he dplyr package, perhaps?

Comment: It *might* be the case that `dplyr`'s behavior changed, but that's a fairly significant one: `dplyr` holds as fairly "resolute" that `select` *always* returns a frame or tibble, regardless of the number of columns (in contrast to normal frames, where `mtcars[,1]` returns a vector but `mtcars[,1:2]` returns a frame), so to have this misbehave "now" seems rather contrary to one of the consistency intentions.